# Почему метод lower() меняет сразу две одинаковых соседних символа?

Tags: python, строки

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему в таком варианте поочередной замены каждой последующей буквы на заглавную происходит одновременная замена буквы "L"? Решение я нашел, а объяснение найти не смог

```
b = ['hello']
for i in b:
    m = []
    for j in i:
        m.append(i.replace(j.lower(), j.upper()))
print(m)
```

```
['Hello', 'hEllo', 'heLLo', 'heLLo', 'hellO']
```

Comment: Потому что вы делаете замену **во всей строке сразу**. `i` - это вся строка. Вы с помощью `i.replace()` по всей строке сразу меняете один символ на другой, вот они все и меняются. Штучные замены символов **нельзя** делать через `replace`, он не для этого.

Comment: Почему вы решили, что это делает функция lower()???

Comment: Наверное потому что я учусь и этот вариант пришел мне в голову. Уверяю, что если бы я знал правильное решение, то не стал бы задавать вопрос

Comment: крайне страннный ответ о причине выбора функции. мало ли что в голову приходит. правильным ответом было бы: "в таком-то месте документации написано то-то, из этого я сделал такой вывод".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что функция `replace` заменяет **все** вхождения первого аргумента в строке на второй.

Работающий код:

```py
b = ['hello']

for i in b:
    m = []
    for index, j in enumerate(i):
        m.append(i[:index] + j.upper() + i[index + 1:])

print(m)
```

Результат:

```py
['Hello', 'hEllo', 'heLlo', 'helLo', 'hellO']
```

Answer (score 1):

у replace есть третий аргумент - сколько раз меняем

```
a = 'qasAAn'
b = a.replace('A', '-', 1)
print(b)  # 'qas-An'
```